# What is the function of voltage divider in the below circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider

Hello I am a beginner in electronics and eager to expand my knowledge in it. Earlier I was trying to build an Ultrasonic receiver using a transducer and some op amps. I ran searches in the Internet and found this: [image: Circuit]

I figured that the signal from the transducer is amplified by the two stages of non inverting amplifiers and fed to comparator for triggering. But why is the voltage divider of resistors \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ used here? Why can't we just feed the input signal directly in to the + terminal of the op amp?

Comment: One suggestion: Feeding the µSonic receiver with 4.5 V, second suggestion: Keeping the input signal between 0 and 9 V with zero at 4.5 V.

Comment: I won't add another answer because the existing ones are exactly correct, but the tl;dr version is: It's not a voltage divider.  At least not for the signal.  In this case, it divides the supply so that the signal ends up centered at that point.  It's exactly equivalent to a single resistor of value R1||R2 between the signal and a "stiff" voltage source of the value that you get from the supply via the divider.

Comment: Also note that if you have multiple signals that all need the same explicit reference via this technique, you can't share them.  At least not directly.  You can do this independently for each signal, which has the problem of component tolerances making them all slightly different; or you can do it once with a lot of capacitance to make it "stiff", and then use single resistors to connect each signal to that.  You might see that done in other circuits, but not this one.

Answer (score 7):

The opamps work with single supply only.

That means: To allow the output to swing above and below the quiescent value this quiescent dc value at the output must be somewhere in the middle between the limits (set by ground potential and Vcc). Hence, the input is biased with 50% of Vcc. This dc voltage is transferred to the output of the opamps because the DC gain is **unity** (caused by the capacitors C1 and c2). The second opamp does not need a separate bias voltage divider because it is dc coupled to the output of the first opamp.

Answer (score 5):

The ultrasonic transducer is a capacitive element. This means it passes no DC current and has no facility to set the DC operating point of the circuit. R1 and R2 set the DC operating point.

If you had a split supply op-amp configuration (+ and - 4.5 volt supplies) because the transducer is capacitive you would need a resistor from input to 0V to set the DC operating point to 0V. Comparing the two types of circuit (single rail and split supplies) a 500k resistor to 0V would be equivalent to R1 and R2 in your circuit.

Answer (score 4):

Redrawing the schematic for convenience:
[image]

Since Z1 offers no DC path to ground, the voltage at the junction of R1 and R2 will be:

$$ E2 = \frac {E1 \times R2}{R1+R2} = \frac{9V\times 1M \Omega}{1M\Omega+ 1M \Omega}= 4.5V.   $$

Then, since an opamp with negative feedback around it will cause its - input to follow its + input, and since R3R4C1 offers no path to ground, U1's output must go to 4.5 volts.

This sets U1's  quiescent operating point for both its input and output at 4.5 volts and will allow its output to swing symmetrically about the operating point between the supply rails.

At 40kHz, - Z1's resonant frequency - the reactance of C1 will be:

$$ Xc = \frac {1}{2 \pi \ f \ C} \approx 4000 \Omega $$

and the AC gain of the circuit will be:

$$ Av = \frac{R3 + R4 + Xc1}{R4 + Xc1} = \frac{1M \Omega + 12k \Omega + 4k \Omega}{12k \Omega + 4k\Omega} \approx 63. $$

There's a small error in there because the reactive term was considered resistive, but it's close enough for the purpose at hand.

The second stage's input and output operating points are set at 4.5V  by the DC output of the first stage, and its gain is also about 63 at 40kHz, for a total voltage gain of about 4000 for both stages.

The output stage uses a rail-to-rail opamp as a comparator with hysteresis, and since the output of the opamp can be at either 9V or 0V, the hysteresis looks like this with pin 6 (the output pin) high and low:

[image]

On power-up, U2's output will go to 4.5 volts, and if we look at the voltage divider comprising R8, R7, and D1, we'll have:

[image]

So, since the output of the divider will always be less positive than U3- at power-up, Vout unconditionally starts up high but, when C3 charges up and gets more positive than U3+, Vout will then go low.

Now, - and here's the crux of the matter - when Z1 sees a mechanical signal to which it's tuned, it'll generate an electrical signal, peaked at that frequency,  which will eventually propagate to the cathode of D1, where it'll be rectified and integrated so that if its amplitude is great enough it'll be able to overcome the hysteretical bias on U3's + input and force Vout high, where it'll remain until the signal on Z1 dies down and U3- goes more positive than U3+